# Make images appear 2 x 2 when only 4 rows are present

Tags: php

I have the code listed below. I have a mysql table set up with links to images. I'm trying to make it where if the result returns only 4 rows total, that the images will have a line break after the 2nd image. This will create a 2 image x 2 image look. As of now, the code adds a line break after every 2 images, no matter how many total images the page displays. Could someone please help with this.

I thought adding if ($i = 4) would work, but it didn't

```
    $i = 0;
    // Gather data from database
    mysqli_data_seek($images, 0);
    while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $images ))

    if ($info['SmallImg']!='Yes')
    {echo "<img src='".$info['ImgPath']."/".$info['StandardImg'].".jpg' alt='".$info['Manufacturer']." ".$info['Style']." - ".$info['ColorName']."' title='".$info['Manufacturer']." ".$info['Style']." - ".$info['ColorName']."' style='min-width:35px; max-width:85px;' />";
    if ($i != 0 && $i%2 == 1){echo '<br />';}
    $i++;}

    else {echo "<img src='".$info['ImgPath']."/".$info['StandardImg']."-Small.jpg' alt='".$info['Manufacturer']." ".$info['Style']." - ".$info['ColorName']."' title='".$info['Manufacturer']." ".$info['Style']." - ".$info['ColorName']."' style='min-width:35px; max-width:".$info['SmallImgWidth']."px;' />";
    if ($i != 0 && $i%2 == 1){echo '<br />';}
    $i++;}
    ;?>
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: The call to `data_seek` should not be necessary here unless you're monkeying around with the cursor. Normally it's best to straight fetch all the data you need into an array and then iterate over that as necessary. The only time you'd use a cursor is if you're dealing with vast amounts of data that can't fit in memory at one time, and even then there's better ways.

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php to know how many results you have.  You can build your logic with that number of total results.

Comment: This approach is likely to have very mixed results depending upon factors like image size, screen resolution etc. I would strongly suggest you look at using css to control your page layout as opposed to hard coding in line breaks. It will give you much more control and allow you to specify different settings for different devices